# Is there an option to circumvent creating an entry in the character advancement log in Genesis 6.1.2 when creating a hero rank >1 character?

Tags: character-creation, character-advancement, tools, splittermond

When creating Splittermond player characters with [Genesis 6.1.2](https://www.rpgframework.de/index.php/de/genesis-2/), how do I create characters with a higher hero rank than 1? Currently, it looks like I have to create an event after regular hero rank 1 creation that awards my character experience points, and then use those to advance them.

Is there an option to circumvent that step as it creates an entry in the character advancement log which I'd like to circumvent.